# How to best represent a group of data with a single value?

Tags: math, cluster-analysis, data-science

I have a cluster containing 5 features(all numerical values) of say 20 persons. I want to represent the cluster with a single value for each feature. Is taking mean of each feature the only best way or is there something more accurate?

Comment: That depends mostly on the feature types and the targeted application.

Comment: Isn't this what clustering algorithms ought to tell you?  Do a K-Means or nearest neighbors and see what it tells you is important.

Comment: As the first comment implies, if you want an answer from us you will need to provide more context. However, this is more of a statistics question than a programming one, so please ask this at the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) site after adding the context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical programming but rather belongs on [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more context.

Answer (score 0):

There are many summary statistics that may or may not be helpful, depending on your application. Each has interesting properties.

- mean
- variance
- mode
- median
- MAD
- skewness
- kurtosis
- ...